# How to get a full URL from a resource URL in python

Tags: python, url

On web pages, resources such as images, css and javascript are loaded by a client's web browser, when embedded with `<img>`, `<link>` and `<script>` tags respectively.

A resource URL can take different forms, it can be a full URL, for example:

```
http://cdn.mysite.com/images/animage.jpg
```

It can be a relative path:

```
images/animage.jpg
../images/animage.jpg
```

Or just a reference to the root

```
/images/animage.jpg
```

How could I create a function in python, that takes the URL of the page, and the URL of a resource on it and ensures that the full URL is returned?

For example:

```
def resource_url(page,resource):
    ## if the resource is a full URL, return that
    ## if not, use the page URL and the resource to return the full URL
```

Comment: Have you looked at the urllib.parse.urljoin method? http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/urllib.parse.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from urlparse import urljoin

def resource_url(page, resource):
  if not resource.startswith(page):
    # doesn't start with http://example.com
    resource = urljoin(page, resource)
  return resource
```